# Android AlarmManager logic

Tags: android, logic, alarmmanager

my android app will remind user of a particular task after every certain time(set by user). There could be as many task a user wants to be reminded of. I know alarm manager is a possible solution to notify user but I don't understand how I will notify user about each task. Will I have to have separate AlarmManger for each with separate Service running for each task? I am new to android programming.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4459058/alarm-manager-example

Comment: @keshav, very thanks for answering but my question was little different. I am confused about how to handle it for multiple tasks. I think your example does not say anything about this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest you to go through [this document at Android Developers guide](http://blog.essencework.com/post/3622739193/scheduling-repeatable-android-notification-in-different) to learn all about services. And to be specific about alarm manager, you may refer [here](http://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/alarms.html).

For reminding different tasks, you may provide unique ids for each intent you fire for particular task as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12797047/1952459).